# How long walking a cat is too long?

Tags: cats, health, safety, exercise

**TL;DR: My cat ended up walking for 1.5 km almost daily. Is it too long?**

Due to some renovations in my apartment, I had to move to somewhere 1.5 km away only for two months. My cat, which was a stray cat who decided to live with me, couldn't come along to my temporary apartment. I stopped by my old apartment daily and contacted others who pet him when he is around to take more care of him.

However, after feeding, he started following me to my new apartment. I never touch or carry him, he follows me on his own. He gets scared sometimes but still follows me. I also take him back to his own turf where he is familiar with the surroundings in the morning.

**This way, he ends up walking at least 1.5 km daily. He hasn't followed me every day so far, so if he does, he will be walking 3 km. Is it too much, assuming that I am monitoring his weight?**

Some details: he is 6 years old, unknown breed - probably not a pureblood, large and relatively chonky. He weighs 6.5 kg and has a tendency to overeat.

When I am done with my studies, I will move to some more permanent and cat friendly location.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you think this is too long for your cat? Does he show signs of fatigue?

Comment: @TotumusMaximus He did show some signs of fatigue in his last walk for the first time. I already reduced my pace a lot for the cat but I will allow him one or two breaks as well.

Comment: The answer given would be mine as well. Just mind that the cat does not wear shoes like you (probably?) and he might hurt himself when the pavement gets too hot. (same counts for dogs btw)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Cats can walk for several kilometers but they will need multiple breaks during the walk, if you are able to give the cat some resting periods during the walk they will be able to handle it.

A cat's body is not made for long continual walks, so they will need to take some breaks during the walk. The problem is, a cat's heart is too small to supply the muscle mass with oxygen for a prolonged time of energy use.

If you keep an eye on your cat and give him breaks when he gets tired, then a walk of 1,5 kilometers is safe - but you will need to be very aware of your cat's condition and remember a slow walk for us is a quick walk for a cat, so you will need to adapt your pace to what is comfortable for your cat.

I have taken most of my cats for walks in the forest where I live without problems. You need to be aware of the temperature when you walk your cat, as cats will easily overheat if you walk him on a warm day; a comfortable temperature for you might be too hot for your cat, so keep this in mind if you take him for a walk.